# Google Tag manager data from events is not visiable in ga4 explorer

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'v configured container for my dev and prod webpages. So the problem is, that my data from events (say view_promotion) is not set in explorer (event 48 hours have passed) from localhost (dev).

NOTE:

- I can connect to localhost through "Preview"
- I installed tag asystant, ga4 extensions, so I can see events, they are appeared inside datalayer, also netwrok have "collect" request, also they are appeared with proper data inside GTM asystant, but I can't see it on ga4 explorer. My question is - do GTM really send events from localhost to ga4 ?  (I use same container for prod, and on prod it works correctly and yes, i use differenet measurement ids, so it really connects to dev env)

Comment: When you preview on your localhost. Do you see the event appear on the debug_view in GA4?

Comment: @darrell-tw can't tell, cuz i see prod devices in debug_mode, but events with proper data appear in my big query